# Unexpected values from insertion loss calculation in IEEE P802.3cg documentation

Tags: signal-integrity, loss, insertion

I'm looking at the insertion loss calculations from [an IEEE document on P802.3cg (10SPE Ethernet)](http://www.ieee802.org/3/10SPE/public/adhoc/1016_cg_adhoc_contribution%20Objectives_Winkel_r04.pdf). On pages 6 and 7 they talk about insertion losses over the cabling in a multi-drop scenario.

I'm following the calculation given here:

[image: Slide from IEEE P802.3cg presentation]

First they define cable insertion loss over 100m as:

$$il_{cable} = 1.23\sqrt{f} + 0.01f + \frac{0.2}{\sqrt{f}}$$

They don't specifically say what this value is measured in, but I'm interpreting this as dB from the context.

Next they define connection insertion loss:

$$il_c \geq 0.05 \\
il_c = 0.02  \sqrt{f}$$

This makes some sense. They're budgeting a minimum value of 0.05dB per insertion, and at the bottom of the page they state that values are valid for frequencies between 1MHz and 30MHz. Assuming that *f* is supposed to be in MHz, then:

$$il_{c(\text{1MHz})} = 0.02 \sqrt{1} = 0.02 \space (0.05) \text{ dB}$$
$$il_{c(\text{4MHz})} = 0.02 \sqrt{4} = 0.04 \space (0.05) \text{ dB}$$
$$il_{c(\text{16MHz})} = 0.02 \sqrt{16} = 0.08 \text{ dB}$$
$$il_{c(\text{30MHz})} = 0.02 \sqrt{30} = 0.11 \text{ dB}$$

These values are within an order of magnitude of the minimum bound they set above, so it seems reasonable that they're expecting *f* to be given in MHz. It also tallies with what they say on page 6, where they talk about 6 connectors resulting in a 0.3dB drop (6 x 0.05dB) at 4MHz, and 16 connectors resulting in a 0.6dB drop (12x 0.05dB) at 4MHz.

Finally they join these together for the case of a 1000m cabling run with 12 connectors, i.e. 10x 100m with 10 inline connectors and one connector at each end:

$$il_{link} = 10  il_{cable} + 12 il_c$$

$$il_{link} = 10 (1.23 \sqrt{f} + 0.01 f + \frac{0.2}{\sqrt{f}}) + 12 (0.02 \sqrt{f})$$

This all seems perfectly reasonable until I put numbers through it: at 4MHz this results in a fairly huge 26.48dB loss, and at 30MHz it's a whopping 72.05dB loss! I'm confused as to what's going on here. Have I made a mistake here? Am I missing something? I can't really get my head around how this system could reasonably operate at 4MHz when the signal is damped to just 4% of its original level by the time it reaches the far end of the cable, let alone at 30MHz when the damping takes it down to 0.025%.

Comment: It sounds about the right ballpark for 1000 metres and 4 MHz. What were you expecting?

Comment: @Andyaka Given that the context of this calculation is that they're "defin[ing] the performance characteristics of a link segment and a PHY to support [...] up to 10 inline connectors using balanced cabling for at least 1000m reach", I don't see how the numbers here demonstrate that they have any hope of achieving that. Yet this is a draft IEEE standard with input from major communications and industrial automation players, and successful feasibility studies from PHY/cabling vendors. I feel like either the numbers and calculations given are wrong, or I'm missing something very critical.

Comment: If you have a data sheet for the cable proposed then that would help sort out this matter.

Comment: @Andyaka According to the available information, it's a single balanced pair of conductors, matching existing standards for 100BASE-T1 and 1000BASE-T1 SPE cables (the latter as per IEEE 802.3bp, now IEEE 8802-3:2017/Amd 4-2017) but the specifications are behind a paywall. The best I found was [this datasheet](https://www.lemo.com/catalog/ROW/UK_English/connector_SPE_single_pair_ethernet_1000BaseT1.pdf) for a 1000BASE-T1 cable.

Comment: Bit of a dead end without the cable. Maybe try Belden website and find one for 1000baset1?

Comment: The bitrate is only 10Mbps. Does it *need* frequencies up to 30MHz to be passed well?

Comment: @user253751 Unsure, but even at 10MHz the loss is -40.7dB (>99%).